# How to access private static class member inherited from a template class?

Tags: c++, class, templates, friend

I'm trying to access static variable inherited from the `EventListener` template, but it looks like the derived `KeyboardListener` class is not a friend of `EventDispatcher`. What am I doing wrong?

```
template <class T>
class EventListener
{
public:
    friend class EventDispatcher;
private:
    static int variable;
};

template <class T> int EventListener<T>::variable;

class KeyboardListener : EventListener<KeyboardListener> {};

class EventDispatcher {
    public:
        static void foo() {
            // this works
            std::cout << &EventListener<KeyboardListener>::variable << std::endl;
            // fails to compile with: 
            // 'int EventListener<KeyboardListener>::variable' is private
            std::cout << &KeyboardListener::variable << std::endl; 
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default inheritance of classes is private.  When you have

```
class KeyboardListener : EventListener<KeyboardListener> {};
```

You are inheriting privately from `EventListener` all the `EventListener` members are private.  I think you ment to inherit publicly like

```
class KeyboardListener : public EventListener<KeyboardListener> {};
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9500f49ef5a0f91)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `EventListener<KeyboardListener>` is a *private* base class of `KeyboardListener` (`KeyboardListener` is decalred using `class`, and you didn't specify the `public` keyword when deriving from the base class). So the conversion from `KeyboardListener` to `EventListener<KeyboardListener>` can only be done by someone who can access the private members of `KeyboardListener`, which `EventDispatcher` can not.

I'd hazard a guess the `private` inheritance is accidental and not what you wanted. But if it is actually desired, you will have to declare `EventDispatcher` as a friend in `KeyboardListener` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class KeyboardListener : EventListener<KeyboardListener> {
    friend class EventDispatcher;
};
```

Comment: That works, but isn't there a better way? I don't really want to friend every single instance by hand.

Comment: @user3129763, I think @Angew 's answer may be what you want. Maybe you need `public` derivation.